# Replace a specific word in entire NSString with a special character using reggae

Tags: regex, nsstring

I need to replace a word like DFT with the registered trademark symbol everywhere in a string from a plist.

My code works but always messes up the second one in the same string:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)addRegisteredTrademarkTo:(NSString*)text
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *rawAttString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"®"
                                                                                         attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:boldFont,
                                                                                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],
                                                                                                      NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @4,
                                                                                                      NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:5]
                                                                                                      }];

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"DRT" options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,rawAttString.length);

    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:text options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

        NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:0];

        [rawAttString replaceCharactersInRange:subStringRange withAttributedString:attributedString];

    }];

    NSAttributedString *t = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:rawAttString];

    return t;
}
```

String is:Fake name™ with Another FakeDRT building access. SionDRT elevators size
Output is:[image]

The second symbol is always misplaced - and I can't figure out why. Any pointers?

Comment: Is your code really working? Isn't your pattern "DRT" instead of "AND" ? Shouldn't `substringRange`  be `[result range]`? The issue seems (but shouldn't be if I remember well), that because you changed the first symbol from 3 lenght to 1, then the second one is messed up (location modificated).

Comment: In the process of editing for publication I mistyped. Your point about symbol length made me try replacing a single character : with the r symbol and that worked. Thank you